# How to store a very large data.frame in an excel workbook?

Tags: r, excel, rjava, xlconnect

I have a very large data.frame, which has 9000 obs. of 1600 variables, and I need to store it in an excel workbook. I have tried `XLConnect` package, but I got this error back:

```
Error : OutOfMemoryError ( Java ): Java heap space
```

I also tried to set the jvm heap size by:

```
options ( java . parameters = " - Xmx1024m " )
```

Unfortunately, it did not work. Besides, I have tried `write.csv()` and `write.table`, but the outputs was wrong. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you say the outputs are wrong, what do you mean? That indicates that your data structure may not be what you think it is. Maybe you show us the error message for `write.table()`.

Comment: I'd make sure that the version of Excel you're using can actually handle 1600 columns. Excel 2003 is limited to 256, for example.

Comment: @HongOoi I am using Excel 2013 and I believe it can handle 1600 columns.

Comment: @vaettchen I mean that the output of `write.table` is not a 9000 times 1600 matrix, but has more than 70000 rows( I inputted it into the excel). It's obviously wrong, and I found that the value in the cells are not consistent with the original data.frame.

Comment: The obvious option would be to create a tab-delimited text file and then import it to Excel: `write.table (table,sep="\t",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,file=file.name)`. If the data is not exported correctly, it means that the data frame itself may be wrong

Comment: @Itamar Thanks for your comment. The data.frame itself is correct. I Managed to get the output correct by eliminating the setting `na=""`, though I don't how it influence the output.

Comment: In my experience, XLConnect is very unreliable at writing large .xlsx files. Writing a .xls file is usually both faster and less error prone, for me at least.

Comment: Are those spaces a mistake? surely it should be "-Xmx1024m"